# How to check if a text contains Jinja2 expressions?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

**The problem:**

Separate files that have Jinja2 expressions from the rest using Python 3 and jinja2 lib

**The question:**

Is there utility method or another good way to check a test for Jinja2 expressions? Or am I stuck with RegEx?

Comment: Render the file using the jinja2 engine. If the output is different than the input it uses jinja2 expressions.

Comment: Thought about that, seems wasteful at best also at that specific place I may not have needed params to render

Comment: Missing parameters would still either mutate the output, or at least raise an error which indicates a jinja2 template. Also are you only interested in built-in tags? Templates may have custom tags, in which case you can only check for the existence of `{{`/`}}` and `{%`/`%}`.

Comment: Thanks. If you format this as an answer I'll probably accept it if no one else comes forward with a better solution